# what is the error in the getGrade() function in student.py

Tags: python, oop

i have a python class called student.py that have attributes and methods but the problem is that when i try to get the grade of the student the function doesn't work as it should and just display the the printing result that contain the name and the grade without the **letter**

the second task i need to get the average of all grades of the student  where this function take as arguments list of grades[]

## student.py

```
class student():
    def __init__(self,name,age, grade):
        self.stdName=name
        self.stdAge = age
        self.stdGrade = grade


    def getName(self):
        return self.stdName

    def setName(self,Name):
        self.stdName = Name


    def getAge(self):
        return self.stdAge

    def setAge(self, Age):
        self.stdAge = Age

    def getGrade(self):
        print("the student {0}, have a grade {1}".format(self.stdName,self.stdGrade))        

        if self.stdGrade >=90:
            return "A"
        elif self.stdGrade >=80:
            return "B"
        elif self.stdGrade >=60:
            return"C"
        else:
            return"F"

        return self.stdName,self.stdGrade

    def setGrade(self,Grade):
        self.stdGrade = Grade



std1 = student("georges", 17, 80)
std1.getGrade()
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? You `return` the letter, but don't do anything with it

Comment: to get the student name with the grade  and the Letter  A OR B OR C OR F

Comment: You _already_ have the letter as you have used `return "A"` in your `getGrade` function. You just don't do anything with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calculating the grade and not using it in your print. Here's how I would fix that: 
`

```
class student():
    def __init__(self,name,age, grade):
        self.stdName=name
        self.stdAge = age
        self.stdGrade = grade


    def getName(self):
        return self.stdName

    def setName(self,Name):
        self.stdName = Name


    def getAge(self):
        return self.stdAge

    def setAge(self, Age):
        self.stdAge = Age

    def getGrade(self):
        gradeLevel = None
        if self.stdGrade >=90:
            gradeLevel = "A"
        elif self.stdGrade >=80:
            gradeLevel = "B"
        elif self.stdGrade >=60:
            gradeLevel = "C"
        else:
            gradeLevel = "F"

        print("the student {0}, have a grade {1}".format(self.stdName, gradeLevel))
            # return self.stdName,self.stdGrade

    def setGrade(self,Grade):
        self.stdGrade = Grade



std1 = student("georges", 17, 80)
std1.getGrade()
```

`